# Unattended installation of MS Office 2007 through PowerShell without Volume License

Tags: powershell, installation, ms-office, office-2007

Recently I've been given a task to automatize the installation of MS Office 2007 through PowerShell. I've tried doing it this way:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process ".\Pakiet Office\MsOffice2007\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/config Enterpriser.WW\config.xml" -Wait}
```

And even though the wizard pops up, during the installation process this is how the window looks:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USqk5.png)

And then after it finishes it displays the [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB1Mx.png) saying that the installation was successful, however after checking I saw that no files were installed. In comparison, when I launch the setup.exe file manually, there's no problem like that.

This is the config.xml file:

```
<Configuration Product="Enterprise">

     <Display Level="full" CompletionNotice="yes" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />
   
     <Logging Type="standard" Path="%temp%" Template="Microsoft Office Enterprise Setup(*).txt" />
   
     <PIDKEY Value="(the key goes here)" />

     <USERNAME Value="Customer" />
   
     <COMPANYNAME Value="MyCompany" />
   
     <INSTALLLOCATION Value="%programfiles%\Microsoft Office" />
   
     <LIS CACHEACTION="CacheOnly" />
   
</Configuration>
```

I didn't change anything in the files, they were provided to me by my client.

At first, I've tried to do it through /admin like this:
`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process ".\Pakiet Office\MsOffice2007\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/admin" -Wait}`

But after some research, I've found out that to use this method you need to have the Office Customization Tool, which isn't accessible due to lack of volume license. I can only work with the files provided, so I'm pretty sure it's out of question.

Later I've tried to change up some values in the config, but in the end nothing was really resolved, so i reverted to the original file.

Comment: FYI: Office 2007 has been end of life sinds 2017. Any piece of code written for such an old piece of software which has been out of support for such a long time while major security related bugs have been introduced in the meantime is a waste of time and should be advised against.